# Return a value to caller function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I need to set the image URI on a state value **previewImage** but the problem is that the value is inside a function. I need to get the image URI from inside the function and return it back to the caller function to save it on the state.

This is the called component

```js
const ImageDisplay = (images, onPress) => {
    
return (
  {images.map((image, index) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress(image)}>
      <Image source={{uri: image}} />
    </TouchableOpacity> 
  ))}
);
```

This the component that calls the above

```js
<ImageDisplay images={images} onPress={viewImage} />
```

And this is what is done on the value that it got from inside the component

```js
const viewImage = (uri) => {
  setPreviewImage(uri);
  console.log(uri)
}
```

The problem is the value I see on the console is not the URI of the image but a bunch of data which is **Class {...}**

**How can I get the image URI from inside the component then return it back to the caller component?**

Comment: What happens if you change `TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress(image)}` to `TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(image)}`

Comment: Welcome to SO, I upvote your question, hope you will be more active on SO.

Comment: `onPress(image)` calls the `onPress` function immediately when you render the component. Instead you need to pass a function to the `onPress` handler of `TouchableOpacity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `onPress` instead of passing it as a function. You want:

```
    images.map(image => (
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(image)}>
            <Image source={{uri: image}} />
       </TouchableOpacity> 
    )
```

This assumes `images` is an array of strings.

Comment: this solved it. lol i got stuck on this for 1 hour now. so stupid hahaha

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a function, by your code in first render it will run:

```xml
const ImageDisplay = (images, onPress) => {
  const pressHandler = () => onPress(image);
    
  return (
    <>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={pressHandler}>
          <Image source={{uri: image}} />
        </TouchableOpacity> 
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```